# What can I do to let someone test my MacBook Pro without going through my stuff

Tags: macbook-pro

I was contacted by a potential buyer who seems interested in my MacBook Pro 2019, they will probably like to test it to see how it is and stuff, that it is fine, the thing is before selling if they decide to buy it I have to format it, if I do it before we meet then they cannot test it, and if they decide to back off then I have to reinstall everything.

What can I do to make it so that they can test it without going through /mess up my stuff/files ?

Comment: In addition to the answer by Nimesh Neema, Meet in a very public place. Do not let them plug in, or connect to, any external device. Nor would I take my eyes off of it and sit so you are in between them and the door/exit route so they cannot get up and run with it without going past you. You would then have a better opportunity to stop them. I'm not being paranoid, just totally realistic!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way to accomplish this would be enable Guest login.

This way, your potential buyers can test out the computer without going through any of your personal data.

To enable Guest user login, go to System Preferences app → Users & Groups, click on Guest User and check *Allow guests to log in to this computer*

[image]